# JQuery: tablesorter how to sort table if tbody doesn't correspond to theader

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

My problem is similar to this : [Tablesorter 2.0.3 colspan issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035056/tablesorter-2-0-3-colspan-issue), but the structure of my table is:

```
<table id="myTable">
<theader>
    <tr>  
        <th>Reference</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Description</th>            
    </tr>
</theader>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">111</td>            
        <td colspan="2">Ok</td>
    </tr>        
</tbody>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

After applying table sorter on this table, it wasn't sorted correctly. Table could be sorted only if click on first and second header. I've tried to adapt the solution from [Tablesorter 2.0.3 colspan issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035056/tablesorter-2-0-3-colspan-issue) to my problem, but got errors inside of jquery plugin.

But should be sorted if click was made on first and third header. 
Also what I've tried to do is to enable and disable headers, like:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
            headers: { 
                  0: { 
                      sorter: true
                  },
                  1: { 
                      sorter: false
                  },
                  2: { 
                      sorter: true
                  },
                  3: { 
                      sorter: false
                  },
});
```

Can some one help me with it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Combine the problem headers into a single cell.

```
<table id="myTable">
 <theader>
    <tr>  
        <th colspan='2'>Reference / Description</th>
        <th colspan='2'><div>State / Description</th>            
    </tr>
 </theader>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">111</td>            
        <td colspan="2">Ok</td>
    </tr>        
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I've did as you recommended me, but now I'm having another problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117662/jquery-table-sorter-stop-sorting