# jQuery Table sorter: stop sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Is it possible to stop table sorting if user clicks on `div` inside of table header `th`?

In my case div has function `onClick="resize(e)"` on which I do:

```
function resize(e) {
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        e.stopPropagation();
        ....
```

But it doesn't work.

*Edit: Table is sorted before `e.stopPropagation()` or `return false`*

Comment: Instead of using the `onClick` attribute, try attaching a click event using jQuery (something like `$("th div").click(function(event){});` and put your resizing code in that function. Then `event.stopPropagation()` might work.

Comment: Thank you, but I've also tried it like Ajay beni indicated

Comment: Can you show a live code or preferably a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made two demos for you. The first one has the content of the table header wrapped in a span and the second one uses the undocumented `onRenderHeader` function to add the `span` inside the header. Either way, only the contents of the `span` are clickable (the text) while clicking outside of the content will sort the column. If you use a `div` only the header padding is available to initialize a column sort.

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/26/) - header contents wrapped in the markup

```
$('table')
    .tablesorter()
    .find('.inner-header')
    .click(function(){
        console.log('header text clicked');
        return false;
    });
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/25/) - header content wrapped using the `onRenderHeader` option

```
$('table').tablesorter({

    // customize header HTML
    onRenderHeader: function(index) {
        $(this)
            .wrapInner('<span class="inner-header"/>')
            .find('.inner-header')
            .click(function(){
                console.log('header text clicked');
                return false;
            });
    }

});​
```

If you need more information on using the `onRenderHeader` option, check out my [blog post](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#defaults) on what's missing in the documents.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this exact problem. I tried everything suggested, including directly assigning a non-delegated event handler to the precise element I wanted, then stopping all propagation + the event itself. Still no luck.

But.... it turns out the jQuery tablesorter assigns an event to the **mouseup** event, not the **click** event (as you'd expect!). So to prevent tablesort from doing it's thing, you just need to cancel that event instead. Hope this helps.

- Ben

Answer (score 4):

Stop propogation prevent event from bubbling up but it you want to cancel default action you should use event.preventDefault()

Comment: Doesn't work. Table is sorted first and then this function is invoked. How to make this function execute before table sorting?

Comment: Dear Andriy i think it depends upon your html structure Suppose you have a scenario like <TH><DIV></DIV><TH> then if you attach a onclick event to TH then the event will bubble from div to TH and then inside onclick function you can check the event source and if it is div you can use stoppropogation to stop bubbling event to TH so the main sorting event will not be fired

Comment: Still sorting :\ by event source you meant `if(event.srcElement.className == "resizer")` ?

Comment: <body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th><div>fadfa</div></th>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <script>
        $("th").on("click", function (e) {
            if (e.target != this) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            else {
                alert("make sorting work");
            }
            
        });
    </script>
</body>

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to just use `return false;`

Comment: Table is sorted before e.stopPropagation() and return false

Comment: My solution is stupid: sort table back when user clicks on div. It works fine with 100 rows, but how it will work with 1000? I believe that there is another way to solve my problem.